# Exporting armature without adding leaf bones - bone size change

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, export, bones

When I export an armature from blender (FBX) the bones at the end of each 'chain' are exported with a minimal length, in blender the length is fine, but in UE/Cascadeur the bones are small. why is that?

Im not adding leaf bones when exporting, I have no need for the extra bones.

Blender armature:

[image]

The exported result (same result both in Unreal Engine and Cascadeur)

[image]

Both fbx and blend file, with armature only can be downloaded from here: https://easyupload.io/m/8td8jh

Comment: Try Importing the model back again to blender to check whether Blender and UE/Cascadeur perceives armatures the same from your .fbx

Comment: When reimporting the FBX back to blender, the bones are a bit larger than they are in the blend file. @YunethAlwis

Comment: That does sound weird. Could you send me the Armature only to test it out and find out what is wrong with it...

Comment: @YunethAlwis i've added linkjs to both fbx and blend in the question post. thanks.

Comment: Okay so I checked it, I tried messing around with the fbx exporter, I still get the same results as yours. I think blender's fbx exporter is not consistent. so I think it cannot be fixed. I hope someone else comes up a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no end bone, FBX doesn't have a way to draw "length" as FBX is joint based. When going from a BONE that is a point and has length.. to a joint system, just a point, you can't have "length" without another child joint just like modeling a polygon line.. you need two verts to have an edge between them
it doesn't change anything about the skinning or the animation.
If the Source rig from a Joint based software has "end" bones or "dummy" bones, Blender doesn't need them EXCEPT if you let FBX auto orient, then it uses the child bone to figure out how to point and orient the Blender bones when FBX import builds the
armature
This can cause issues like root joints that should be world aligned end up pointing at the spine joint and creating an angle or tilt in all the animations
It gets more complicated because, since those "end" joints are for display only in a Joint Based system, they aren't always there, some people leave them off and out of the skinning or only put them in for some parts not others so you can end up with a mix of end/no end bones and so if you say, don't import them, you end up removing joints that SHOULD be there